# Does Realtek RTL8192SU driver support access point mode

Tags: linux, wifi

Trying to set-up a Raspberry Pi as wireless access point connected to my router. Using a Realtek wireless dongle:
lsusb:
Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8191SU 802.11n WLAN Adapter

Tutorials I am using mention access point capabilities of the wifi adapter as a prerequisite.

Is this dongle usable for my project?

Comment: Before you can configure it as an AP, the adapter has to be working. Is the adapter showing up when you do `ifconfig` and `iwconfig`?

Comment: Yes it is showing up there.

Answer (score 2):

Type `sudo apt-get install iw` , iw is a utility that can manipulate wireless devices and their configurations. After installing it type `iw list` , it will print a list, under **Supported interface modes :** if you see AP, then it means it supports. For finding that faster you can type `iw list | grep AP`

Comment: It gives me an error : nl80211 not found.

Comment: @dastaan did you make some configuration yourself or downloaded someone's hostapd?

Comment: No. I didn't. I just tried installing iw package. After installtion when I tried to run iw list, it threw me that error.

Comment: What's your dongle's driver?

Comment: It is 8192cu, i guess

Comment: I also have an extra 8192cu and it also gives nl80211 not found, most probably the reason is that it doesn't support AP mode, I've tried to set up an access point with that earlier but didn't work. Instead of it I use an RT5370 and I can get iw list output with that one

Comment: Isn't `iw list` for listing modes along with other data ? I guess it has nothing to do with adapter supporting AP mode. I've not played with things so can't be sure.

Comment: http://blog.sip2serve.com/post/48420162196/howto-setup-rtl8188cus-on-rpi-as-an-access-point I found this article explaining it while googling the error. Could be helpful for other who stumbles across this answer.

Comment: I saw that one too but he doesn't check iw list again in that post and I'm sure it'll still print nl80211 not found, ctrl+F nl80211 here : http://www.pi-point.co.uk/documentation/ I shared idea of the guy here who says it might actually mean it doesn't support an AP mode but you're right.